# Secure WebAPi, Windows Phone and MVC Website

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 app and a ASP.NET MVC 5 website and each of these will access a WebApi service (WebApi 2). The website and WebApi are based on the templates provided by VS2013 RTM and have been setup using the "Individual Account" authentication option available in the project template.

The template sets up the WebApi project to enable bearer tokens, application cookies and external login cookies, etc, and the exposed actions have the Authorize attribute on them.

My two questions are:

1) If I were to use Azure Mobile Services to authenticate a user using Google/Twitter on the WP8 application how can I get the WebApi to allow the authenticated user to access the actions?

2) Same as #1, but from a ASP.NET MVC 5 website perspective?

From I what I can see it would appear that each request requires a bearer token. To get this token would I be correct in thinking that I would access the "token" endpoint exposed by the WebApi to get the token and that would need to be passed with each request?

Comment: Why are you using Azure Mobile Service in this scenario? You can use OWIN external authentication middlewares to login user from google/twitter. Is it a required component in your question?

Comment: The main reason for mobile services was it manages loading of a browser to request the provider credentials from the user. The plan is for a Windows 8 app at some point and in that instance I was going to use the WebAuthenticationBroker. Basically I just not sure on the flow between the app, the provider (Goolgle/Twitter) and the WebApi.

Comment: It looks like that you just miss a WebAuthenticationBroker in phone app. You don't need to setup a mobile service for that. You can just use mobile service sdk code to launch a browser control and you can point it to your web api endpoint. The sdk code is open sourced. You can find it at https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.WindowsPhone8.UI/Authentication/AuthenticationBroker.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1, you can use [azure mobile service WP8 sdk](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/Managed/src/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.WindowsPhone8.UI/Authentication/AuthenticationBroker.cs) to launch a browser control to authorize user from external site. The code should be similar with WebAuthenticationBroker in windows store app.

For 2, the web api template with individual auth is using an [implicit flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) in OAuth 2.0 to return the application access token back to client. In MVC app, you can redirect user to

```
http://<web api domain address>/api/account/externallogin?provider=Facebook&redirect_uri=<your callback url in MVC app>&response_type=token&client_id=mvc.
```

And in your MVC view, you need to use javascript to get access token from url fragment, which won't be sent to server. In your web api server, you need to allow the client id and the callback url in ApplicationOAuthProvider.

For both 1 and 2, you are not using token endpoint to get the token. You are using the authorize endpoint to get token by implicit flow.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that not only implicit flow but also resource owner password flow can be used to obtain a valid oauth2 token. This allows to have a custom auth interface instead of relying on the browser automation.

Comment: For the WP8/Win8 app I can authenticate a user with an external provider and get the access token, but in order to access the WebApi I need a bearer token. This, I'm assuming, means taking info from the response from Google/Twitter and passing it to the WebApi similar to this example which uses a username/password (http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api). This example sends a request to http://localhost:port/Token with the content "grant_type=password&username=Alice&password=password123". How would I do a similar thing, but for an external provider?